# Exchange 2010 Management Console Mailbox Icon

Tags: exchange-2010

Can someone tell me what exact type of a mailbox this icon represent?
I can't find any information on this.
I have uploaded a picture of it to the below link:

http://prntscr.com/8gch45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, that is a linked mailbox.